# Jquery not running even after including it in my html

Tags: php, jquery, html

So i'm trying to put my jquery in a js folder saved as script.js and then just call the file in my html. So i tried to call it before my css, after my css and even just right above where my  ends yet my jquery is not running. Can anyone identify my issue? Here's how i tried to call my script.js in my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php include '/php/db.php'; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paprika" rel="stylesheet">



<title>YFC</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div id = "container" method="post">
        <div class="signup">
            <h1>Sign up</h1>
            <form action="/action_page.php">
              <input class="pop" type="text" name="Sname" placeholder="Fill in your name!"><br><br><br>

              <input class="pop" type="password" name="Slastname" placeholder="Fill in your last name!"><br><br><br>

              <input class="pop" type="text" name="Susername" placeholder="Fill in your username!"><br><br><br>

              <input class="pop" type="password" name="Spassword" placeholder="Fill in your password!"><br><br><br>

              <input class="pop" type="password" name="SRpassword" placeholder="Repeat your password!"><br><br><br>
              <input class="sbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="signin">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
              <input class="pop" type="text" name="Lusername" placeholder="Fill in your username!"> <br><br><br>
              <input class="pop" type="password" name="Lpassword" placeholder="Fill in your username!"> <br><br><br>
              <input class="lbutton" type="submit" value="Log in">

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my jquery code

```
$('.pop').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('width',300);
});

$('.pop').mouseleave(fucntion(){
     $(this).css('width',280)                

});
```

Comment: try wrapping you code inside this `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your JS code when the DOM is available for use. Right now you're trying to use the `.pop` elements before they exist.

To do this in jQuery you can use a document.ready event handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pop').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('width', 300);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css('width', 280)                
  });
});
```

However there's a couple of things to note here which can improve the quality of your code. Firstly you shouldn't put CSS rules in your JS code. Instead create classes and then use any of the jQuery class amendment methods (`addClass()`, `removeClass()`, `toggleClass()`) to add/remove it as needed.

Also you can use `hover()` to run code under both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. If you couple that with `toggleClass()` you only ever need to provide a single handler function:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pop').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');              
  });
});
```

```css
.pop { width: 280px; }
.pop.hover { width: 300px; }
```

Taking that a stage further still, then you don't even need to use JS code at all. You can use CSS's `:hover` selector to amend the element when the mouse is over it, like this:

```css
.pop { 
  width: 280px; 
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  margin: 2px;
}
.pop:hover { width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="pop">Pop</div>
<div class="pop">Pop</div>
<div class="pop">Pop</div>
```

Comment: hmmm okay i see it works now thanks :) but why didn't it work when i called the .js at the end of my body tag? Because the DOM should be available right? Since i called the .js file at the end ?

Comment: At that point it should work. I can only assume the issue there was due to your typo - `fucntion` instead of `function`.